# Mocking HTTP request in unit test

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, moq, xunit.net

I start learn Moq and I have this problem. I need mock class/interface which make HTTP GET and HTTP POST request and return HTML string as server response.

I simplified my code. Here is:

```
public interface IHttpManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Make HTTP GET request on server and return HTML string
    /// </summary>
    string HttpGet(Uri url, CookieContainer cookies, HttpRequestSettings settings);

    /// <summary>
    /// Make HTTP POST request and return HTML string
    /// </summary>
    string HttpPost(Uri url, string postData, CookieContainer cookies, HttpRequestSettings settings);
}
```

I use `IHttpManager` in class `ConnectionManager` which make log in or log off on server.

```
public interface IConectionManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Connect to server and parse HTML response
    /// </summary>
    Result<T> LogIn(string nick, string password);

    /// <summary>
    /// Log off and parse HTML response
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="account"></param>
    void LogOff(Acccount account);
}

public class ConnectionManager : IConectionManager
{
    private IHttpManager _httpManager;
    private HttpRequestSettings _httpRequestSettings;

    public ConnectionManager(IHttpManager httpManager, HttpRequestSettings httpRequestSettings)
    {
        _httpManager = httpManager;
        _httpRequestSettings = httpRequestSettings;
    }

    public Result<Account> LogIn(string nick, string password)
    {
        // I simplified this method

        // How correct mock IHttpManager, because it must return HTML string
        // so in Moq in Setup return hard coded HTML string which represent server response ?
        string htmlStringResponse = _httpManager.HttpGet(ServerUrl.LogOn, new CookieContainer(), _httpRequestSettings);

        // parse HTML string and return result
    }

    // ...
}
```

I unit test for method `LogIn`. I would like to mock `IHttpManager`. But I don’t how to do in correct way.

I try this:

```
// Arrange
var mockHttpManager = new Mock<IHttpManager>();

mockHttpManager.Setup(x=>x.HttpGet()).Returns(()=>"HTML SERVER RESPONSE");

var sut = new ConnectionManager(mockHttpManager.Object, new HttpRequestSettings());

// act
sut.Login("nick", "123")

// Assert
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you need to set up the parameter expectations on your mock:

```
mockHttpManager
    .Setup(x => x.HttpGet(
        It.IsAny<Uri>(),
        It.IsAny<CookieContainer>(),
        It.IsAny<HttpRequestSettings>()))
    .Returns(() => "HTML SERVER RESPONSE");
```

Ideally, you should use `It.Is<T>()` to match the arguments, to ensure that the method is called with the exact parameters you expect. For example, you may want to test that your `Login` method calls `HttpGet` with `ServerUrl.LogOn`:

```
It.Is<Uri>(uri => uri == ServerUrl.LogOn),
```

Comment: Thanks. But my real problem is different. I would like to know if return HARD CODED HTML STRING is correct way for mock IHttpManager.Get with Moq. If not what is correct way? I am not sure that return hard coded string is good manners.

Comment: OK. That wasn't clear. Well, you need to return HTML responses that can be parsed by your `LogIn` method, and then assert that the `Result<Account>` object that's returned is what you expect. You'll need to return different strings for different tests, e.g. log-in succeeds, log-in fails, server wasn't available, etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It exist different way how to mock IHttpManager? Something better?